# Eigenvalues of $5 \times 5$ matrix with real entries from given condition

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-polynomial

Suppose that $M$ is a $5 \times 5$ matrix with real entries and $p(x)= \text{det}( xI - M)$, then which of the following is true?

1. $p(0)= \text{det}(M)$
2. Every eigenvalue of $M$ is real if $p(1)+ p(2) = 0 = p(2)+ p(3).$
3. $M^{-1}$ is necessarily a polynomial in $M$ of degree $4$ if $M$ is invertible.
4. $M$ is not invertible if $M^2- 2M= 0.$

Option $1$ is false for $M= I_{5}$ , since then $p(0)= -1$ but $\text{det}(M)= \text{det} (I_{5})= 1.$ 
Also for $M= 2I$, $4$ is false.
$3$ is true by Cayley- Hamilton theorem, but I'm unable to construct a counter- example for $2$. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: How do we know $det(M)$ is 1 though?

Comment: @sai-kartik for option $1$, I took $M= I_5$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 is $\color{red}{\text{false}}$, since if $M(M-2)=0$, then $x(x-2)$ is the minimal polynomial of $M$ and since the characteristic polynomial must be a multiple of $x(x-2)$ and therefore at least one of the eigenvalues is zero  which means $M$ is not invertible ($M$ is singuar), $\color{red}{\text{unless }M=2I}$ and that's why this statement is false, the only exception is $M=2I$.

2 is $\color{red}{\text{false}}$, since $p(x)=x^5+bx^4+cx^3+dx^2+ex+f$ is a monic polynomial of degree 5. with the given conditions we get two equations

$$\begin{cases}17a+9b+5c+3d+2e+33=0 \\
97a+35b+13c+5d+2e+275=0\end{cases}$$

by solving for $(d,e)$ and substituting in the characteristic polynomial $p(x)$ we get
$$p(x)=x^5+ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+(-4c-13b-40a-121)x+(\frac{7}{2}c+15b+\frac{103}{2}a+165)$$ This equation is very general and by a simple substitution of $a=b=c=0$ we get the polynomial $p(x)=x^5-121x+165$ which has two complex roots, so in general the second statement is false.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed solution.

Comment: So what about $M=2I$ for (4)? How do you know $x(x-2)$ is the minimal polynomial of $M$?

Comment: Yes you are right. (4) is correct except if $M=2I$. The [minimal polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)) is the monic polynomial of the least degree that $p(M)=0$ and since $M\neq 0$ the hypothesis $M^2-2M=0$ means $x(x-2)$ is the minimal polynomial (least degree after 1 is 2). But as you mentioned the only and only exception is $M=2I$. I correct the answer.